# Consequences of having a gas giant as a neighbour instead of Mars

Tags: planets, earth, astronomy, gas-giants

Assuming we had a gas giant instead of Mars in our planetary system. Everything else stays the same. Which long-term and short-term consequences for life on Earth would I have to take into account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are describing a "magical swap" since every thing else remains the same.

Short term, basically no change — currently Jupiter's gravity effect on earth is about 100,000 times weaker than that of the sun. At closest approach in its new orbit, Jupiter's would be about 8 times closer and its gravity would be about 64 times stronger, still over 1500 times weaker than solar gravity.

I.e., tides, and other short term effects would be a non-issue.

Long term, is likely a much more interesting question. Jupiter's influence on Mercury's orbit is already considered to make Mercury's orbit unstable over a period of billions of years. I.e., Mercury could fall into the sun, collide with Venus or even collide with Earth -- the system is chaotic and we cannot accurately predict which of the outcomes will occur, any are possible. A much closer Jupiter would simply increase the unpredictability and Mercury could perhaps reach one of these endpoints in 100 million years (possibly a little less).

Since Mars orbit has a period a little over 3:1 with respect to Venus, I would expect that the new Jupiter orbit would eventually result in a 3:1 resonance with Venus. A resonance orbit like this would destabilize the orbit of Venus relatively quickly, so it is entirely possible that Venus could crash into Earth before Mercury gets the chance.

If mars was placed in Jupiter's orbit, it would also become unstable over a long time as the gravity of Jupiter and Saturn would both act to destabilize the new Mars orbit.

Finally, although a chaotic and unpredictable system, it seems likely that Jupiter would also destabilize Earth's orbit over the very long term.

---

The new Jupiter orbit would result in a very eye-catching object. At maximum brightness, Jupiter is currently magnitude -2.94, Mars is -2.91, Venus is -3.82, and a full moon is about -12.74. After the change, Jupiter would be as bright as -7.45, and still about -5.35 at minimum brightness.

Assuming Jupiter's moons were included in the new orbit, some of them would also be visible to the naked eye. The largest moons are actually bright enough to be visible in Jupiter's current orbit, but the human eye cannot resolve them separately from Jupiter.

For comparison, the brightest star is Sirius, apparent magnitude -1.46.

Venus is already so bright that people mistake it for a UFO on a regular basis. Imagine how people would react to a sudden change in Jupiter's orbit.

Comment: A more interesting scenario would be putting Jupiter in Earth's orbit and having all of the terrestrial planets orbit it

Comment: How visible would Jupiter be from Earth, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @NexTerren - updated answer for visibilty

Answer (score 1):

Earth would probably never form if the gas giant was there since the beginning.

[The gravity from Jupiter kept the planetesimals of the asteroid belt from coallescing into a planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_belt#Formation). Jupiter's orbit is farther form the asteroid belt than Mars's orbit is from Earth's orbit.

So we would probably have an extra asteroid belt in the inner solar system.